# outputing textbox values to another window using PURE javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a novice javascript developer, would like to get help and a mentor in Javascript developement.

My question is how can I output values entered in a textbox to a new window using pure javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by a new window?  Can you be more specific in what you are trying to do?  Your question is quite vague and will likely attract downvotes.

Comment: Sir, what I mean is when the person clicks on the submit button, a new window (or tab in the browser) opens up with the text the person entered in the text field.

Comment: You cannot do this purely with Javascript.  You are submitting data to the server hosting the page, thus you need a server side script to handle the data.  PHP is a common server side language you could use.

Comment: Alright sir, I thank you for your help, I will then have to study PHP. I appreciate your response.

Comment: you can do this in javascript. look at my answer. you only need PHP if you need to submit the data to a server.

Comment: You don't need to specify pure JavaScript. If you don't tag your question `jquery` or some other library, the assumption is that you are looking for solutions not using a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your solution with pure JavaScript

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>   <title>JavaScript new Window</title>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   function newWindow() {
>       var a=document.getElementById('name').value;
>       var b=document.getElementById('email').value;
>       var w= window.open();
>
>       w.document.write("name :"+a+" email :"+b);
>   }
> </script>
> </head>
> <body>
> <form id="f1" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="newWindow(); return false">
>   Name : <input type="text" id="name" /><br>
>   email : <input type="text" id="email" /><br>
>   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
> </form>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

source: [Output Form Values in New Window using pure JavaScript](http://www.javabase.info/output-form-values-in-new-window-using-pure-javascript/)